# Angular2: Observable flatMap error Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, flatmap

I'm using Angular 2 final version and trying to perform HTTP request that depends on another HTTP request.

My case is trying to *getAccount* with user id as parameter which returned from another http request (*getUser*)

AccountService:

```
constructor(private http: Http, private userService: UserService) {
    }

getAccount(): Observable<Account> {

    let tenant: string = 'test';

    Observable.fromPromise(this.userService.getUser()).flatMap(
        user => {
            return this.http.get('/tenants/' + tenant + '/accounts/' + user.id + '/')
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    return res.json();
                });
        });
}
```

UserService (depends on external system, works as required):

```
getUser(): Promise<User> {
    return new Promise<User>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (KeycloakService.auth.authz.token) {
            return KeycloakService.auth.authz.loadUserInfo().success((data) => {
                resolve(<User> data);
            }).error(() => {
                reject(null);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

When calling to getAccount from AppComponent.ts:

```
this.accountService.getAccount().subscribe(data => { console.log('account:', data); });
```

I'm getting the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

any ideas what causes this error?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

A `return` is missing

```
return Observable.fromPromise(this.user
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear this fixed your problem :-)